# ORACLE TABLE: How to add the sum on the bottom part of the output and compute its overall total

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a table called as "Home_Expense"

```
 CREATE TABLE HOME_EXPENSE
(
First_Name VARCHAR(15),
Last_Name  VARCHAR(15),
Electricity INT,
WATER INT,
TOTAL int
);
```

And I inserted some values

```
INSERT INTO HOME_EXPENSE VALUES ('OwnerAName','OwnerALast','1000','900','');
INSERT INTO HOME_EXPENSE VALUES ('OwnerBName','OwnerBLast','1000','900','');
```

The output should be:

```
 First_Name          Last_Name          Electricity          WATER     TOTAL
 OwnerAName          OwnerALast         1000                 900            
 OwnerBName          OwnerBLast         1000                 900
```

The output that i want is to have a Total on the bottom part which is this:

```
 First_Name          Last_Name          Electricity          WATER     TOTAL
 OwnerAName          OwnerALast         1000                 900            
 OwnerBName          OwnerBLast         1000                 900   
 ---                 ---                2000                 1800
```

Using this syntax Sum(Electricity), Sum(Water) , i can get the sum of the electricity and water, but how do i place it on the bottom part and get its overall total (3800)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grouping sets`:

```
select first_name, last_name,
       sum(electricity) as electricity, sum(water) as water,
       sum(total) as total
from home_expense
group by grouping sets ( (first_name, last_name), () );
```

Note:  This assumes that `first_name`/`last_name` are unique.

You can always do the equivalent with `union all`:

```
select first_name, last_name, electricity, water, total
from home_expense
union all
select null, null, sum(electricity), sum(water), sum(total)
from home_expense;
```

`GROUPING SETS`, though, is a nice enhancement to learn about.